# Please add prefers-color-scheme CSS

Tags: feature-request

Can something like

```
<style>
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { 
    body, pre, a.question-hyperlink, #content {
        background: black;
        color: white;
    }
}
</style>
```

be added to unix.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 3):

From [the announcement of Dark Mode on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/4751173):

> #### Future releases
>
> At this point, the focus of Dark Mode is on Stack Overflow and we’ll eventually bring it to MSO. While the retheming we did across the network two years ago makes updating our LESS easier, creating dark versions of all of our sites, particularly the custom-designed ones, is going to be a huge challenge we’re not able to contemplate at this time.

So they've *considered* a dark theme for Unix & Linux Stack Exchange sites and other sites in the network, but they aren't going to do it in the near future, so I expect your feature request to be [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

But nobody will stop you from using a custom stylesheet (through a browser extension) from rolling your own dark theme. Or use existing plugins; a couple of solutions are mentioned in the answers to [Dark Mode for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111399/295232).

Comment: "Huge challenge" seems like an overstatement, when Stack Exchange could just let users submit solutions, and copy paste the most popular answer.